# How to catch javascript exceptions/errors? (To log them on server)

Tags: javascript, error-handling, error-logging

#### Duplicate:

> - [Automatic feedback on JavaScript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546990/automatic-feedback-on-javascript-error)
> - [Logging JavaScript-Errors on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-javascript-errors-on-server)

---

How would I go about logging errors in javascript? I can't wrap every line of javascript in try catch block.

I talking about the errors that for example in IE, would show an Error On page message and have the line and char the caused the error. If I can just figure out how to catch this error on the client side, I can just log the error on the server using an ajax call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch all JavaScript errors and send them to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328154/catch-all-javascript-errors-and-send-them-to-server)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I use this function in all my projects:

```
window.onerror = function(m,u,l){
    jQuery.post("ajax/js_error_log.php",
        { msg: m,
          url: u,
         line: l,
       window: window.location.href });
    return true};
```

Make sure it is the very first javascript the browser receives or at least precedes any potentially error-causing code.  Requires jQuery of course, but you could code ajax functions in pure javascript if you wanted to.

Please note: this will not help you if you have a syntax error.  All javascript instantly dies if there is a syntax error.

Comment: Heh... Just linked to a previous question where you gave *nearly* the same answer. You're really on the ball when it comes to JS error logging! :-)

Comment: lol...  It's funny you caught that, and I don't even *remember* answering that question.

Comment: @George Jempty: Read my explanation.  I gave jQuery because it's fairly pervasive and much more succinct to type out.  The example is valid as it's simply a model.  I didn't give the source code for my php script or the layout for the MySQL table storing the errors either.

Comment: Ideally I wanted a jQuery answer but I didn't want to restrict the answer to that. Thanks

Comment: I have just released code to help log JavaScript errors by sending error information to the server - 
http://www.thecodepage.com/post/JavaScript-Error-Notifications.aspx