# JavaScript catch ReferenceError when including scripts

Tags: javascript, debugging, prototype, referenceerror

Suppose something like

```
<script src="http://mydomain.tld/buggy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get in my console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

I can't tell the developers to wrap the code in try/catch, but nonetheless would like handle that error on every client. I saw that overriding/extending `ReferenceError` is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712995/how-can-i-override-extend-referenceerror-in-chromes-javascript).

I also tried the following (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253652/how-do-you-send-console-messages-and-errors-to-alert)):

```
function handleError(evt) {
if (evt.message) { // Chrome sometimes provides this
  alert("error: "+evt.message +"  at linenumber: "+evt.lineno+" of file: "+evt.filename);
} else {
  alert("error: "+evt.type+" from element: "+(evt.srcElement || evt.target));
}
}
window.addEventListener("error", handleError, true);
```

Which pops up a message almost like I'd want to `"error: Script error. at linenumer:0 of file:`

Can I make it include the original error message (`Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined`)?

Comment: You may want to look at `window.onerror`.

Comment: I had done that before as well, sorry I hadn't mentioned that. Used the snippet from https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-with-window-onerror-even-on-chrome-and-firefox/ which results in `Èrror: Script error. Script : Line:0 Column:0 StackTrace:null`. Is it because it's cross domain?

Comment: Same here. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) the handler should also receive the `ReferenceError`, but in latest Chrome I got `null` as the fifth parameter. I got stuck here.