# Is there any way to log browser console errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error, frontend

Suppose a particular user is using Chrome, and gets a runtime error which is logged in Chrome's Console. I'd like to know what that error is. Currently I would have to reach out to the specific user, get them to open up the console and tell me what the error is (or send a screenshot).

Is there a way for me to automatically catch or log that error (regardless of what the error is) and send it to the server?

As a follow-up question is there a way to do this for all major browsers?

Comment: There are various tools/libraries that do this. Have a look at [Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/for/javascript/) for one example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch all JavaScript errors and send them to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328154/catch-all-javascript-errors-and-send-them-to-server)

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap console.log and console.error with your logging method

```
var log = console.log;

console.log = function() {
    //Ajax post arguments to your server for logging
    return log.apply(console, arguments);
};

var error = console.error;

console.error = function() {
    //log arguments to server
    return error.apply(console, arguments); 
};
```

Comment: What about errors that are generated by the browser and not something I specifically log myself? If the browser is unable to parse a JSON response (as an example) the browser will log an error. I'd like to know about it. Would the above take care of this scenario?

Comment: No, it won't but it'll get logs and errors sent by any JS code. If you want to log browser errors as well you can use window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    //ajax log to server ('Error: ' + errorMsg + ' Script: ' + url + ' Line: ' + lineNumber);
}. HTML 5 onerror sends col, error as well.

Comment: More details have been given in the following link for the questions of @AllenS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors