# Catch browser Javascript exception in production and send notification

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, exception, monitoring

I have Rails 5 app, in this app I use gem 'exception_notification'.
This awesome gem, sends me email notifications if something went wrong in production mode.
But this notifications only for rails backend.

Can you advise me an some analog JS lib for Javascript frontend in browser.

My goal catch JS exceptions in browser in production mode send some request to server and then server send me notification(email) with error description, stacktrace info and so on.

I know about window.onerror event.
But in that case I should handle all of it manualy.

May be there is some JS lib with turnkey solution?

Thank You.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328154/catch-all-javascript-errors-and-send-them-to-server check this question

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to use

```
var deviceAPIloaded = false,
    gOldOnError = window.onerror;

window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, columnNumber, error) {
  if (! deviceAPIloaded) {
    $.getScript('https://theapicompany.com/deviceAPI.js', function() {
      deviceAPIloaded = true;
      sendErrorInfo(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, columnNumber, error);
    });
  } else {
    sendErrorInfo(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, columnNumber, error);
  }

  if (gOldOnError) return gOldOnError(errorMsg, url, lineNumber);

  return false;
}
```

In function sendErrorInfo gathering error and device info and POST it to server.