# global javascript error handling

Tags: asp.net, javascript, error-handling, global

Is there any way to catch Javascript errors globally across the web application by writing some code in the master page?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546990/automatic-feedback-on-javascript-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205688/javascript-exception-handling and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119432/logging-javascript-errors-on-server and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript global error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951791/javascript-global-error-handling)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `onerror` event:

```
var oldOnError = window.onerror;
window.onerror = function()
{
    alert('Something bad happened');

    //Optionally...
    oldOnError();
}
```

Comment: I have just released code to help log JavaScript errors by sending error information to the server - 
http://www.thecodepage.com/post/JavaScript-Error-Notifications.aspx

Comment: Do you possibly know why this simple demo - http://jsfiddle.net/YM9U7/ - works in IE9 beta and Firefox 3.6, but doesn't work in Chrome, Safari and Opera? (By "works" I mean, the "Error!" alert is displayed.)

Answer (score 0):

See [JavaScript Exception Handling Techniques](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/javascript_exception_handling_techniques.aspx)